Efficient pseudo-inverse solution of $Ax = b$ without full SVD
Consider the pseudo-inverse solution of the system $Ax= b$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ an $m \times 1$ vector. Both $m\ge n$ and $m < n$ are relevant to me. In mathdotnet numerics, there is a function to get the pseudo-inverse of a matrix via SVD. This seems a bit overkill:

You don't need memory for $U$ of $A = U ~ s ~ V^T$, nor build $U$ explicitly, since you can apply the pieces which contribute to $U$ directly into $b$.
You don't need to get the actual singular values. You just need to single out the nullspace of $A$, and make sure $x$ doesn't have components in this nullspace.

Consider $m \geq n$, you could do a QR-decomposition on $A$ yielding $A = Q_0 ~ R_1$, detect that all diagonal elements of $R_1$ are numerically nonzero, and solve the system $R_1 ~ x = Q_0^T ~ b$. Of course you do that without storing $Q_0$, but multiplying the pieces which contribute (e.g. Householder transforms) directly into $b$. This doesn't work when there's a numerical zero on the diagonal of $R_1$, even if you make $x$[row of zero diagonal element] = $0.0$, since you then typically have components in your solution $x$ which are in the nullspace of $A$.
You could work via bidiagonalization (for $m \geq n$ with upper diagonal $R_2$ and $m < n$ lower diagonal $R_2$):
$$A = Q_1 ~ R_2 ~ Q_2$$
You apply the pieces of $Q_1$ into $b$ directly, but are required to keep $Q_2$ either as such, or implicitly (Householder vectors, ...). If there's no numerical zero on the diagonal of $R_2$, you can solve $R_2 ~ y = Q_1^T ~ b$ easily, and obtain $x = Q_2^T ~ y$. If there is a numerical zero, you can divide and conquer $R_2$. Consider the case of an upper bidiagonal $R_2$, but the same arguments hold for a lower bidiagonal matrix:
[ a b        ]
[   c d      ]
[     0 e    ]
[       f g  ]
[         h  ]

By flipping the off-diagonal elements to the other side, the bidiagonal matrix can be separated into disjoint blocks. This can be done in the example by:

post-multiplying with Givens rotations from the top left corner downwards, in the example for column pairs $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$, and
pre-multiplying with Givens rotations from the bottom right corner
upwards, in the example for row pairs $(3, 4)$ and $(2, 3)$ [using
counting from $0$]. We then have

$$A = Q_3 ~ R_3 ~ Q_4$$
with $R_3$:
[ p          ]
[ q r        ]
[     0      ]
[       s    ]
[       t u  ]

In the example, for the system $R_3 ~ y = Q_3^T ~ b$, $y[2]$ is obviously $0.0$. This correctly ensures there's no contribution of the nullspace of $A$ in $x$. The blocks before and after the zero can be dealt with separately:

no numerical zero => solve
numerical zero => divide and conquer, as noted above.

I have the feeling I'm rediscovering something that already exists. Do you now of literature / lapack implementations which perform pseudo-inverse application more efficient than full SVD building?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I've received an answer on https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/discussions/1006
Citing verbatim:

To solve overdetermined ("m >= n", least squares) or underdetermined
("m <= n", min "x" 2-norm) linear systems, you have to look at the
GELS family.
Arbritrarily using D as the prefix, you have DGELS, DGELSY, DGELSS and
DGELSD.
If the coefficient matrix is full, then have a look at DGELS. This is
based on a straight up QR factorization. The method breaks if A is
rank-deficient and the method does not perform well if A is
"numerically rank-deficient".
If the coefficient matrix is rank-deficient or "numerically
rank-deficient", then have a look at DGELSY, DGELSS or DGELSD.
DGELSY is based on the complete orthogonal decomposition of A. (So
based on a QR factorization with pivoting, and then COD.)
The method you are describing is most related to DGELSD. DGELSD
reduces to bidiagonal form, and then solves the bidiagonal linear
least squares problem (or min x 2-norm problem or a combination of
both).
DGELSS is based on the SVD of A.

